# JQuery scrolling text plugin which supports add/remove

Tags: jquery, plugins, scroll, ticker

There are a number of JQuery plugins that support scrolling text right to left.

We are looking for one that supports dynamically adding or removing items from the list.

Ie: You are scrolling 3 text messages, you do an AJAX poll to get the latest data, then you want to add 2 new messages and remove 1 existing messages, and do so without having a 'jumpy' UI experience.

Also, ideally we would like to be able to highlight the color of a given message for a fixed amount of time.  Ie: highlight the 2 new messages (in the prev example) in red for 30 seconds.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean something like a newsticker which is updated behind the scenes when it's scrolling?

Comment: Yes, I guess that is what I mean ;)